# What should we do if we have query related to rarely used concept?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that only those post gets more view and up votes which are related to commonly used topics such as

> 'how to read data from sql server using SqlDataReader'

whose answer can any one (freshers) gives. But those question which are new or rarely used concept such as

> Xamarin, HDF5 etc

could not get enough views as many peoples are new to that topic. And SO have rule that if your question is not that much popular then they will ban you from posting question. So what can we do for it?

Comment: You can put a bounty on a question. You can also share it on social media, using the "share" link under the question.

Answer (score 14):

> SO have rule that if your question is not that much popular then they will ban you from posting question

Huh? Since when?

The rule is about **low quality** and **bad** questions. Nothing to do with popularity or rareness of the subject.

> So what can we do for it?

Make sure the question itself is on-topic, as described in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), tag it well, ensure it is of [good quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

And wait.

Comment: please go through it http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: They mentioned there about zero voted question

Comment: @MohiniMhetre That's only if you have a ton of them. One question with zero won't ban you. And if it's that rare and difficult, and you write the question well, it's very likely to get upvotes.

Comment: It is possible for a question to be deleted due to low views and a score of 0, if the question is older than 365 days: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006 . With SO being as active as it is today, I could imagine that otherwise good questions get deleted in this way.

Comment: @MohiniMhetre - sure. Which have more to do with bad, low quality, off-topic questions than with how popular a subject is. If you a ask a good, high-quality question in whatever tag, chances are good that it will be upvoted.

Comment: @Oded I just want to say that if many people will not see your question how will you get up votes?

Comment: @MohiniMhetre - there are still hundreds of users even on small tags. A good post will get upvotes. Even one is enough.

Comment: @MohiniMhetre Zero-vote questions are but one indicator taken into account. Even if you have a couple of zero-vote questions, you won't automatically get banned. Try to understand the *spirit* of this mechanism, not the (vague) letter of the law. SO does not punish *unpopular* questions, period. If you do happen to actually stumble into what you feel is an undeserved question ban, post here to have someone look into it. The algorithm is not meant against *you*, if you get caught in it tell someone so it may be improved.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know where you read that asking questions about lesser-known technologies would get you into trouble. I'd honestly appreciate it if you told me precisely where you heard that in comments - we're aware that there are some *very ill advised* employee training manuals that certain companies are using to try and 'teach' people how to use the site. If anything you read tells you anything other than:

> Put thought into your question. Search and make sure it hasn't been asked before. Try your best to debug or solve the problem, make sure you tell the other users what you tried in your question. Include the relevant (and only the relevant) code needed to demonstrate the problem. Make sure your question is easy to read, and uses proper grammar, punctuation and spelling to the best of your ability.

.. then it is total, absolute and categorical rubbish.

You're welcome to ask any valid programming question about any technology, as long as they don't look like this:

> plz help me function not returning valid pointer in getEntityFrame(). plz show some example 2 dis hurry is urgaent.

That's not a comical example, that's an example of the pure, lazy and *awful* crap that makes real experts in the topic want to stop using the site. If you know someone that was blocked, it was because they didn't think enough of us to put any actual effort into what we show to millions of people every day. Occasionally folks just get off on the wrong foot, and they're welcome to [contact us](http://stackoverflow.com) if that's what happened. We just need *some* evidence that they can ask good questions, and just didn't realize what they came to ask about wasn't a good fit.

Getting banned for talking about a lesser known subject? Hogwash, bull warts and finklesteins.

Comment: Those Finklesteins are dangerous. I should know, I went to school with one.